# Access apple device images

Tags: image, cocoa

Does apple provide a way to access the device images shown in the scheme editor drop down? I'm looking to access images for iPhone, iPad etc.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing fully documented, but CoreTypes.bundle contains various device images under names such as “com.apple.iphone-4-black.icns”.

Create a bundle object for the bundle, then ask it for the URL for an image resource by the desired name:

```
[coreTypesBundle URLForImageResource:@"com.apple.iphone-4-black"]
```

Exactly which devices are represented in that bundle depends on what version of OS X and iTunes are installed.

Inside of *that* bundle is *another* bundle named MobileDevices.bundle. That one is installed by Xcode; it's in the MobileDevice.pkg package that Xcode installs on first launch and whenever you update it. You may find that newer devices are only present there; that's how it is on my system.

I believe you will need to create a separate bundle object for MobileDevices.bundle to query it; it won't be covered by querying CoreTypes.bundle.

CoreTypes.bundle contains a whole lot of Macs and is the only place for those; MobileDevices.bundle contains all of the iOS devices (up to whatever was current when the installed version of Xcode came out) and is the only place for some of them.